# Последовательность действий

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, текст, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток!

Как с помощью jQuery сделать последовательность выполнения действий через некоторое время (не анимации, а в данном случае - изменение текста)?. Допустим так: Site, SIte, SiTe, SitE?
Пробую setInterval'om, но думаю, что не то совсем. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 3):

вам нужны методы queue и dequeue

не очень-то оптимизированный [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/gaRZx/)

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно.

Comment: Метод, предложенный @Fike не просто неоптимален, он ужасен, он противоречит здравому смыслу, его место на [специализированном сайте][1]. Представьте, что вам таким образом надо анимировать слово `internationalization`. Что, будете набирать 20 вариантов написания? Вот более адекватный способ: http://jsfiddle.net/xU8rr/. И да, начсёт реализации всего этого через jQuery: http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif


  [1]: http://govnokod.ru/

Comment: @fori1ton, можете наказать меня, если хотите.

Comment: @Fike, к сожалению, не могу. А стоило бы. Для чего, по-вашему, придумали компьютеры? Для того чтобы автоматизировать рутинные действия. Вы же, судя по вашему коду, в упор не желаете этого делать. И ладно бы вы сами себе тихонько копипастили однотипные куски кода, но вы же учите этому других людей. ИМХО, пропоганда говнокода - это очень полхо.

Comment: @fori1ton, все вы можете, не стесняйтесь.

Comment: @Fike, я-то на велосипеде катаюсь, а вот вы ковыляете на костылях. Ещё раз: основная претензия не к использованию jQuery (хотя без него там вполне можно обойтись), а к тому, _как_ вы меняете текст. Вы про циклы что-нибудь слышали? А про массивы? И ещё раз, если не поняли: _научитесь программировать сами, прежде чем учить других_. И да, мой пример тоже немного избыточен - использовать `map` для перевода одной буквы в верхний регистр - это слишком. Вот несколько подправленный пример: http://jsfiddle.net/xU8rr/1/

Comment: @fori1ton, боже, как можно быть таким занудой  
1. Я написал пример на коленке за минуту  
2. Чтобы показать как работать с очередями  
3. И даже написал об этом  
4. Я вам гарантирую, что автор столкнется с тем, что ему нужна очередь, а не простая итерация, еще не раз  
5. Все-таки я наблюдаю какой-то невиданный уровень занудства  
6. Тут было много про производительность, но у меня в результате кончились сиволы    
7. Довольно странно в одном комментарии обсуждать обучение людей и писать "пропоганда"  
Идите в вуз преподавать, ей богу, найдете родственные души.

Comment: 1. Я тоже написал пример на коленке за минуту
 2. Чтобы показать, что вы решаете поставленную задачу наименее адекватным способом
 3. И даже написал об этом
 4. Я вам гарантирую, что автор столкнется с тем, что из-за незнания ванильного JS он будет писать подобные костыли, и не раз
 6. Все-таки я хоть нмного забочусь о том, станет ли автор нормальным программистом или пойдёт по шаткой стезе говнокодинга
 7. Не стесняйтесь, напишите отдельный комментарий, подискутируем
 8. Закончились аргументы - придеритесь к правописанию!

Comment: > шаткой стезе говнокодинга

а оттуда и до наркотиков недалеко, да

Comment: @fori1ton, вопрос ТС был про "Последовательность действий", а не про "Способ индивидуального изменения регистра букв в строке". Пример @Fike наглядно показывает принцип, непосредственно имеющий отношение к вопросу.  Поняв его, завернуть то же самое в цикл ТС сможет и самостоятельно.